# Back button won't localize automatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, back

I've got A and B view controllers, both can be accessed from C view controller. When I open A, back button localizes just fine (2 languages), but when I open B it always says "Back". Both controllers initialized this way:

```
UIViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ParkingViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

**UPD:**

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem);
```

returns (NULL). How is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use standard back button, below is what you can do...

Let's say you are in screen 1 & you will be going to screen 2.

Step 1 : in viewWillAppear write `self.title = "Screen 1"`;

Step 2 : While going to screen 2, write `self.title = localized_back`

***Back button always take the previous screen title.***

Comment: I don't really like using patches like this. But, if I won't find answer I'll have to :( Thanks for the answer.